# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/Img/products/image.png'

Tags: next.js, multer

, I've build a new next js app , when i upload images from the browser i stored them in the public/Img/product using multer , and it works in the localhost but when i deploy it throws me
**ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/Img/products/image.png'**
That's my code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function(req,file,cb){
     cb(null,'./public/Img/products')
  },
  filename: function(req,file,cb){
     cb(null,file.originalname);
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage
})
  
  apiRoute.post(upload.single('image'),(req,res) => {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO `Produit`( `Nom`, `image`, `prix`, `Description`, `Quantite`, `promo`, `id_cat`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    connection.query(sql,[req.body.name,`/Img/products/${req.file.originalname}`,req.body.price,req.body.description,req.body.qty,req.body.promo,req.body.categorie],(err,result) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.send(result);
      });
      console.log(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/Img/products/${req.file.originalname}`,req.body)
  });
```

If any one know what's going on just respond me and I  !

Comment: Where are you hosting this to, is it a platform like vercel or another type of host? Additionally, have you verified that node has access to read/write to this directory - it might be a good idea to create the directory upfront, set permissions and then deploy the app

Comment: Hi , I 'm hosting this to vercel , And like what i said in the localhost is work but when i deploy it to vercel it throw me an error that no directory